'list' object is not callable
Наткнулся на такую проблему
  File "C:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    @bot.message_handlers(commands=["start"])
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Сам код:

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')


@bot.message_handlers(commands=["start"])
def main(chat):
    bot.send_message(message.chat_id, 'Дарова')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Помогите пожалуйста

Ну, во-первых, не @bot.message_handlers, а @bot.message_handler, без s в конце - это избавит от вашей ошибки. Но дальше в вашем коде есть еще 2 ошибки. Замените def main(chat): на def main(message): и message.chat_id на message.chat.id. Итоговый ваш код должен выглядеть так:
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Дарова')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)

